# Unable to copy files using COPY on Windows 2003 Server with long name and special characters

Tags: windows, file, copy, filenames

I have thousands of files in a batch file which I need to copy so I prepare a batch file containing copy command as mentioned below. A few files fail to copy with the message 
"The system cannot find the file specified." These entries come from a database.

**copy  "G:\csdata\maximo\ATTACHMENTS\MM#2103806321038064-4’’&6’’X4’’X1500N-LINECHOKEVALVEMOD-4CPC.msg" g:\sample /Y
copy  "G:\csdata\maximo\ATTACHMENTS\Re-doPR70072095withaddinganotheritem21037549TAPE&HEADER-ASSY#THAB2317-70M–QTY2EA.msg"  g:\sample /Y**

As alternative to this, I then used VB script as mentioned below but when a file is missing at OS level the script stops, It should continue to copy next file instead:

**Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFile  "G:\csdata\maximo\ATTACHMENTS\FW91536140-WF3VB4754RPLPASSING18”-VB505LLHDRVLV.msg", "g:\sample\"
FSO.CopyFile  "G:\csdata\maximo\ATTACHMENTS\FW18VALVEFORLLPF1359361065881.msg", "g:\sample\"**

please advise what is the best possible way?

Answer (score 0):

Maximo may allow you to upload/attach files that have characters that are more difficult to process in a batch file. For example, the double quote as part of the file name may confuse the COPY command into thinking that you want to copy G:\csdata\maximo\ATTACHMENTS\MM#2103806321038064-4 rather than the full file name.